# duplicate websocket writing

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm new in `NodeJS` and I would appreciate help with duplicate socket writing.

I have the following code in my client part of application and when something happens, I'm sending an alert to the server:

```
    socket.emit('change', {alertType: ALERT_TYPE});
```

And on the server side I have this:

```
    var app = require('express')()
       , server = require('http').createServer(app)
       , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
       server.listen(3000);

    io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
       socket.on('change', function (data) {     
           io.sockets.emit('change-done', data); 
       });
    });
```

And if more people are using the app I get multiple socket writing like this:

```
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"change-done","args":[{"alertType":"waiting_delivery"}]}
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"change-done","args":[{"alertType":"waiting_delivery"}]}
debug - websocket writing 5:::{"name":"change-done","args":[{"alertType":"waiting_delivery"}]}
```

And the number of these `sockets` writings increases as more people are using this. How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you please provide a little bit more client code. Did you debug the client and made sure, that the emit function is just called once?

In my case sometimes it happened that I registered events multiple times which lead to this behaviour.

Comment: I'm pretty sure emit function is called only once. When someone clicks on a button do this:

http://pastebin.com/DQWZejRN

I update the database and when it's done I call emit function.